# Select Count from Two Tables = Multiplication in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, count

I randomly tried running a query like:

```
select count(*) from table1, table2
```

The result was essentially multiplication of the actual row count of the two tables, i.e. the result was 645792 rows based on the fact that `table1` had 868 rows, and `table2` had 744 rows.

Is this an expected behaviour, I checked out the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) but could not get any better understanding of this behaviour.

Comment: Check about cross join, It may help you

Comment: What don't you understand from the manual? What other research did you do? What is the first subexpression that returns what you don't expect? When you have a specific question it will be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your `from` clause:

```
from table1, table2
```

This is equivalent to:

```
from table1 cross join table2
```

This is a cartesian product of both tables, which generates a resultset containing 868 * 744 rows. Then `count(*)` just counts the number of resulting rows, hence the result that you are getting.

If you wanted to sum the number of rows in each table, you would compute two separate counts:

```
select
     (select count(*) from table1) 
     + (select count(*) from table2) total_no_rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current query:

```
select count(*) from table1, table2
```

is using the old school implicit join syntax.  As there is no join criteria appearing in a `WHERE` clause (there is no `WHERE` clause), the join defaults to being a *cross* join.  This is just the cross product between records in the two tables, which is what you are currently seeing.  A better way to write your query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

'INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Correct, but it should be noted that not all flavors of SQL support inner join without an `ON` clause (MySQL does, and in this case, the inner join becomes a _cross_ join).